# Are there four dimensional generalizations of the Reuleaux triangle and other solids of constant width?

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, solid-geometry

Is there a four dimensional generalization of the Reuleaux triangle? What is it called, and what properties does it have?

Thank you!

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: You might be interested by this [article](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/353245502_Peabodies_of_constant_width/link/60ef183e9541032c6d3e878b/download) even it it deals with 3D issues.